# Sorting a HashTable by the values (including alphanumeric)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashtable

I have a `HashTable` with alphanumeric values. I want to **sort** them.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, try to make your questions' titles **as short/expressive as possible**. Also, help others to **understand** what you mean. Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`HashTable` doesn't preserve the order.

So better Create a `List` out of it and Sort it.

You need to wrap your types into a class and then implement a Comparator that compares all the types of values (in your term),

```
class Foo implements Comparator<Foo>{
  private int no;
  private String alpha;
  //+getter/setters

  public int compare(Foo f1, Foo f2){
      //put your logic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why? You presumably chose HashTable over TreeMap because it had better performance (and no ordering). If you don't want the performance and you do want the ordering, use a TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new class to hold the key/value relationship and it you are not interested in a TreeMap, then something like the following will also work:

```
ArrayList<Entry<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String,String>>();
list.addAll(map.entrySet());

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String,String>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, String> o1, Entry<String, String> o2) {
        //your logic here;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First question - do you really mean sort the values, or do you mean sort the keys?

If you only want to access the sorted values in order once the best way is create a list or array then sort.

For values: `Arrays.sort(table.values().toArray())` or `Collections.sort(new ArrayList(table.values()))`

For keys: `Arrays.sort(table.keySet().toArray())` or `Collections.sort(new ArrayList(table.keySet()))`

For more on these sorting methods: [Arrays.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) or [Collections.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

If you want to repeatedly use based on sorted keys, you would be better using a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

If you repeatedly want to access based on sorted values (rather than keys), then you could always insert in order into a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which will keep the ordering.